# How can one find which paths have been deserialized by a job run from YARN (e.g. Spark or Hive)

Tags: apache-spark, logging, hive, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I want to know which paths on HDFS are deserialized by each job that is being run on my cluster.

Is the list of paths deserialized by each job somewhere in the standard logs of Spark/Hive? Are they at the ApplicationMaster level, the level of the task, or the level of a task attempt?

Comment: I found the Hive directories deserialized under `syslog_dag_...` by searching using `grep "splits for dirs"`

Comment: For Spark, I found paths deserialized looking for `FileScanRDD` operations in the `stdout` of the executor logs